# How to change current_user password?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to let user edit his/her profile in the website and I am done with most of the part except password update.

This is the form that I use for password update:

```
<div class="title">Change Password</div>
<div class="password">
  <%= profile_error_messages_for(@profile) %>

  <%= form_for :user, url: change_password_path do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'attribute', 'password', id: nil %>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:current_password, 'Current Password') %>
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:password, 'New Password') %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:password_confirmation, 'Password Confirmation') %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag 'Change Password', class: 'btn btn-success btn-md input-width-large' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

As you can see, I also have `<%= hidden_field_tag 'attribute', 'password', id: nil %>`, which I use to determine, which form I am submitting. Because I have couple more form in a page. For example email update form, and that one has `<%= hidden_field_tag 'attribute', 'email', id: nil %>`. There is no problem here so far.

This is my update method in profile_controller:

```
 def update
    @profile = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)

    if params[:attribute] == 'email'
      if @profile.update_attributes(email_parameter)
        redirect_to request.referrer
      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    elsif params[:attribute] == 'password'
      if User.password_match?(params[:current_password])

      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
  end
```

Email, part works fine but I gotta make password part work.

I have this in my user.rb model, which I use for authentication.

```
  def self.password_match?(entered_password = '')
    password == User.hash_with_salt(entered_password, salt)
  end
```

And as you saw, I am trying to call this from my method. Because I have to check if user entered the current_password field correct.

But when I submit password update form, I am getting this error message:

```
undefined local variable or method `password'
```

I don't know what should I do.

**edit**

this question is answered here: [Params are empty after form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32982482/params-are-empty-after-form-submission/32983004#32983004)

Comment: Are you using devise?

Comment: @AntarrByrd No. I made my own.

Comment: Have you tried using it as an instance method?

Comment: I am sort of new to ruby. What do you mean use it as instance method? when you say instance, I just know @variable.

Comment: please post the full code and the error logs

Answer (score 1):

Since you have defined a instance method in `User` model

```
def password_match?(entered_password = '')
    password == User.hash_with_salt(entered_password, salt)
end
```

this method is only available to a instance say `@profile = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)` here `profile` would be a instance of `User` class so, that method would be available to `@profile` not `User`
so,

```
def update
    @profile = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)
     .
     .
     .
    elsif params[:attribute] == 'password'
      if @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password])

      else
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
  end
```

For more info about instance and class method see
http://www.railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/
https://cbabhusal.wordpress.com/2015/08/05/ruby-various-ways-to-define-class-methods/

Comment: Well, looks like we are on the right track but when I put the correct password in the form, it doesn't go in the if statement. What I thought is that in 'password_match?' I accept password to check if password matches. But in your example, I am sending the all object into 'password_match?'. How can I submit the password only? I tried this:       if @profile.password.password_match?(params[:current_password]) BUT I got this error again: undefined method `password_match?'

Comment: I guess `@profile.password` return a string so it should not respond to `password_match?`. make sure you have defined the method `password_match?` in `public` scope; i.e. not after `private/protected` keyword

Comment: you try like I have suggested; the error `undefined local variable or method password'` should not come.. the `password` method will be responded by `User`'s instance in `@profile` object

Comment: I found where the problem is but still trying to fix. password form do not pass the params. I tried typing 'put password_entered' in 'password_match?' and when I submit the form, it doesn't display anything but when I login to the site, it displays the password there.

Answer (score 1):

user controller:

```
def update
  @profile = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)

  if params[:attribute] == 'email'
    if @profile.update_attributes(email_parameter)
      redirect_to request.referrer
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  elsif params[:attribute] == 'password'
    if @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password])
       if @profile.update_attributes(password_parameter)
         # redirect_to #...
       else
         render 'edit', notice: 'Failed update password, password too short or whatever'
       end
    else
      render 'edit', notice: 'Please enter your current password / Current password is incorrect'
    end
  end
end

private
def password_parameter
  # code
end
```

user model:

```
def password_match?(entered_password = '')
  self.password == User.hash_with_salt(entered_password, self.salt)
end

# I assumed the password and salt method is already defined
# you have to define it first if it is not defined
def password
   # ...
end

def salt
   # ...
end
```

Comment: your method seems correct but somehow, if @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password]) does not return true. Even though, password_match? is correct. Because it works with login.

Comment: I assumed there is 3 password fields, the first one is the original password field, so user have to enter his old password first, then user is authorized to changed his password, the next 2 fields is 'password' and 'password confirmation' fields, so password and password_validation must contain equal value, you can make more validation if you wish

Comment: when @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password]) doesn't return true, it was mean user entered incorrect old password

Comment: I know and I tried the correct password but it still doesn't work.

Comment: is the password in database hashed? if so, please check are you using correct salt?

Comment: yes, it is hashed. and password_match? checks it with salt. It takes the password and takes the salt from database and checks it. And it works when I login to the site. I have been working on it since 3 days :D. It is soon that I am gonna jump off the balcony =)

Comment: okay, I've just tried putting this inside password_match?, puts entered_password puts salt and I see that entered_password is empty. So, it doesn't even go there.. weird. at least I know where the problem is now.

Comment: exactly. it doesn't submit any values inside. I am gonna google it.