# Params are empty after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a from, where users can change their passwords. For now, I haven't done anything about updating the password because my form doesn't pass params for some reason. Before, I give you the code, just to let you know, you will be seeing `puts` inside command for debugging purposes.

Password Form:

```
<div class="title">Change Password</div>
<div class="password">
  <%= profile_error_messages_for(@profile) %>

  <%= form_for :user, url: change_password_path do |f| %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'attribute', 'password', id: nil %>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:current_password, 'Current Password') %>
        <%= f.password_field :current_password, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:password, 'New Password') %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <div class="input-box">
        <%= label_tag(:password_confirmation, 'Password Confirmation') %>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control input-md input-width-large' %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag 'Change Password', class: 'btn btn-success btn-md input-width-large' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

profiles_controller:

```
elsif params[:attribute] == 'password'
  puts 'params: ' + params[:current_password].to_s

  puts 'here 1'
  if @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password])
    puts 'here 2'
  else
    puts 'here 3'
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

User model:

```
  def password_match?(entered_password = '')
    puts 'Password: ' + entered_password.to_s
    puts salt
    password == User.hash_with_salt(entered_password, salt)
  end
```

where ever I tried printing out value, it is empty. we don't even need to check model. because when I typed this in controller, it is also empty.

```
puts 'params: ' + params[:current_password].to_s
```

I have been working on this problem since 3 days. Please somebody help me =). Thank you.

Comment: I think you should try `puts params.inspect` and see if it's really not there.

Comment: Is there a chance you're filtering them out in your controller (you didn't provide the whole controller code, so I can't tell)? If you're using strong parameters, you'll have to whitelist those that you want the front-end to pass to your server. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters

Comment: @limekin I didn't know this. It actually removed [FILTERED]. okay when I tried this I see that all my output is there. but why is it nil when I passed it in password_match?

Comment: I putted all my controller. and I also have strong parameters but I am not using them yet.

Comment: Did you notice when you inspected that all the fields you want are wrapped under `user` ?

Comment: @limekin these are the parameters: "user"=>{"current_password"=>"ghdgdh", "password"=>"ghgh", "password_confirmation"=>"gh"}, so looks like when I try :user in puts, it prints but when I try :current_password it doesn't. how can I reach current password which is inside :user

Comment: @limekin ahaha at the same time.

Comment: :D. Yeah should use `params[:user][:current_password]` to access the value from the nested hash.

Comment: @limekin last 3 days I tried fixing this problem and these 3 days thought me so many thing thanks to you guys :D you may wanna answer this question. I am gonna select it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better to inspect `params` itself if you are unsure about the presence of a field or where it is located in the hash returned by `params`.

When you use `form_for` helper, the fields when submitted will be wrapped under the lowercase model-name of the resource (or simply the name) you pass in for `form_for`. So in your case, since you have given the `:user` name, the hash returned by `params` will contain a key `'user'` under which all of your fields will be present with their given structure. So you should use :

```
params[:user][:current_password]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `params[:user][:current_password]` in your controller.

Answer (score 1):

@cyonder, since you are new to Rails/Ruby its our responsibility to at least give you some idea that may help you:

## Debugging in Rails:

We use debugging tools like [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry), [bye-bug](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debugging-with-the-byebug-gem)

Using these tools (pry) you can put `break-points` in code so that the server execution stops at that point and you can analyse the object's value in that particular point of execution.

For Example:

```
elsif params[:attribute] == 'password'
      binding.pry

      if @profile.password_match?(params[:current_password])
        binding.pry
      else
        binding.pry
        render 'edit'
      end
    end
```

When you send HTTP request; `binding.pry` stops execution and you can get access to `rails-console` in the terminal you are running server `rails s`

Something like this

```
[1, 10] in /PathTo/project/app/controllers/articles_controller.rb
    3:
    4:   # GET /articles
    5:   # GET /articles.json
    6:   def index
    7:     binding.pry
=>  8:     @articles = Article.find_recent
    9:
   10:     respond_to do |format|
   11:       format.html # index.html.erb
   12:       format.json { render json: @articles }

(pry)
```

After this I hope you can debug your app your self.
For more info see

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#debug
http://railscasts.com/episodes/280-pry-with-rails